# File Search In PC name VB6

Tags: vb6

Hope your vast base of knowledge can help here,

im looking to create a search and open code,

I want to search for the PC Name (Have that bit done) and use that name to search for a text file within a folder. The file will contain a single line of data which i want to use to configure the page which my system logs out to, if the file is not present i want to open a file named default and use the data line within it.
ie. the bit im stuck on is the ability to check a folder for a file whos extension will alwavs be the same but whos name can change from pc to pc. 
reason being i need to validate and test the programming, if i change the logout page data within the code it will need to be tested each time we need to change it. this way updating a list of text files named after each pc with the approiate logout data is all that will be needed to change.

there is plenty of resources out there for VB.NEt struggling to find stuff for VB6.

PS. very green at this.

thanks
Attached code for review if anyone has the time,

thanks again

```
Type Point_Type
x As Long
y As Long
End Type

'Allows user to set logout duration
'Logout Duration = timer interval x 19
'Change timer interval or max LogoutCheckCounter to change duration
 Dim LogoutCheckCounter As Integer

Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (lpPoint As Point_Type) As 
Long


Private Declare Function apiGetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long


Public Sub InacLogOut()

On Error GoTo Err_

Dim CheckUser As String
Dim coord As Point_Type
Dim retval As Long
Dim xPos As Long
Dim yPos As Long
Dim line As Integer
Dim page As integer
Dim LogoutTime As String
Dim LogoutPage As String
Dim MyComputerName As String
Static xOldPos As Long


'get current cursor position
retval = GetCursorPos(coord)
xPos = coord.x
yPos = coord.y

'code executes every 30 seconds

'If mouse is not moved the old position nwill equal t r log in default user
If xOldPos = xPos Then

'get the current user
 CheckUser = System.LoginUserName

 If CheckUser = "NOBODY" Then
    'User is already logged out, exit sub without action
   Exit Sub

Else      
    'get logout time 
    line = FreeFile
    If Dir("C:\LogoutTime.txt") <>"" Then
       Open "C:\LogoutTime.txt" For Input As line
       Line Input #line, LogoutTime
       MsgBox (LogoutTime)
       Close File
     Else 
     LogoutTime = 10
     End if

    ' get logout page
    MyComputerName = fOSMachineName

    Dim  FiletoOpen as string
 FiletoOpen = "C:\" & MyComputerName & ".txt"

    If Dir(FiletoOpen) <>"" Then
        Open "FiletoOpen" For Input As page
        Line Input #page, LogoutPage
        MsgBox (LogoutPage)
        Close File
     Else 
     LogoutPage = MainPage
     End if

      'code executes every 30 seconds, LogoutCheckCounter used to set the 
  logout interval
    If LogoutCheckCounter > LogoutTime Then
     ' code to kill report tool if open
        Shell "taskkill.exe /f /t /im ReportGenerator.exe"
        msgbox (Kill task)

        User.ReplaceCentralFrame LogoutPage
        System.FixLogin "NOBODY", ""

      Else
        LogoutCheckCounter = LogoutCheckCounter + 1
      End If
  End If

 Else
    'mouse has been moved, reset LogoutCheckCounter
    LogoutCheckCounter = 0

End If

'xOldPos will initially be zero the first time the code runs
xOldPos = xPos
Err_:

End Sub
'-----------------------------------------------
Function fOSMachineName() As String
Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
Dim strCompName As String
lngLen = 16
strCompName = String$(lngLen, 0)
lngX = apiGetComputerName(strCompName, lngLen)
If lngX <> 0 Then
fOSMachineName = Left$(strCompName, lngLen)
Else
fOSMachineName = ""
End If
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------`
```

Comment: Do you also want to make a coffee? You're asking for something impossible.

Comment: Nothing is impossible; just difficult. i have the code reading the PC name and oppening the folder which contains the text file named after the PC. i just need a way to join the found file name(pc name) and the known extension. for example, on PC-001001 i have a file in C:\LogoutCode\ with the PC name. PC001001.txt i just need a way to join the path to the string...... "C:\LogoutCode\" && "PC001001.txt" and thanks for the fast response

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/concatenation-operators

Answer (score 0):

It's done a bit differently in VB6 than what Marc referenced. You don't declare and initialize the variables on the same line in VB6. Following the Microsoft examples:

```
Dim x As String
Dim y As String

x = "Mic" & "ro" & "soft"
y = "Mic" + "ro" + "soft"

Dim a As String
Dim d As String
Dim z As String
Dim w As String

a = "abc"
d = "def"
z = a & d
w = a + d
```

The "&" operator can use any data type and the variable will be converted to string. The "+" operator only works with strings and will throw a compile or run time error if any variable or literal is not already a string.

```
Dim a as string
Dim x as long

x = 123
a = "abc" & x
results  in "abc123"

a = "abc" + x
results in an error
```

So

```
Dim strPath as String 
Dim strName as String 
Dim strFileSpec as String 

strPath = "C:\LogoutCode\"
strName = "PC001001"
strFileSpec = strPath + strName + ".txt"
```